# Referencing folder without absolute path

Tags: python, path

I am writing a code that will be implemented alongside my company's software. My code is written in Python and requires access to a data file (`.ini` format) that will be stored on the user's desktop, inside the software's shortcuts folder.

This being said, I want to be able to read/write from that file, but I can't simply reference the desktop as `C:\USERS\DESKTOP\Parameters\ParameterUpdate.ini`, since the absolute path will be different across different systems.

Is there a way to ensure that I am referencing whatever the desktop's absolute path is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows, desktop absolute path looks like this:

```
%systemdrive%\users\%username%\Desktop
```

So this path will fit your requirements:

```
%systemdrive%\users\%username%\Desktop\Parameters\ParameterUpdate.ini
```

Please make sure u don't actually mean public desktop path, with will be:

```
%public%\Desktop\Parameters\ParameterUpdate.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'Parameters', 'ParameterUpdate.ini')`.

Answer (score 0):

on Windows you can use to get Desktop path:

```
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
```

Comment: Would this matter if the user doesn't have a windows machine?

Comment: On Unix or Linux you can use :

    `import os`
    `desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~')), 'Desktop')`